# Nested lists in angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material2

Can you nest Lists in Angular Material?

I haven't seen any [examples in the documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/list/examples).

I guessed that I should use a [multiline list](https://material.angular.io/components/list/overview#multi-line-lists), but I'm doing something wrong.

[Things that I have tried.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h)

Comment: Btw I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44374200/angular-2-material-nested-md-list-item) question, it's for an older version of the framework.

Comment: So you have the answer? https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h-xppmzz

Answer (score 34, accepted):

As indicated by [@Vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468463/vega) in the comments, you can't nest a `<mat-list>` under a `<mat-list-item>`, but if you ngFor another div that contains them both, it's still ok, and the `<mat-list>` line height is correct.

Here is an example by [@Vega](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5468463/vega): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nnkg3h-xppmzz

```
<mat-list>
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of items">
        <mat-list-item>{{item.name}}</mat-list-item>
        <mat-list style="margin-left:30px;">
            <div *ngFor="let subItem of item.subItems">
                <mat-list-item>{{ subItem.name }}</mat-list-item>
            </div>
        </mat-list>
    </ng-container>
</mat-list>
```

Answer (score 2):

There is now an Angular Material "tree" component, which is basically a list of nested lists similar to a file structure. If that it what you are looking for you can find it here: https://material.angular.io/components/tree/overview